# %jdbc(hive) - Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri

Tags: hive, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run some hive queries using JDBC driver on Zeppelin.

When I run this command,     `%jdbc(hive)`

I get following as the response error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Following is my hive-site.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?><!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
--><configuration>
<property><name>hive.metastore.uris</name><value>thrift://hive-metastore:9083</value></property>
<property><name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name><value>false</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name><value>jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore-postgresql/metastore</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name><value>org.postgresql.Driver</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name><value>hive</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name><value>hive</value></property>
</configuration>
```

Following are the Interpreter properties and dependencies.

[image]

**Updates**

I found below in `/tmp/root/hive.log` file. So, the root cause must be at hive-metastore.

```
    2019-01-14T10:58:56,379 INFO  [main]: hive.metastore (:()) - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://hive-metastore:9083
.....
.....
2019-01-14T10:58:59,660 INFO  [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:stop(476)) - Shutting down HiveServer2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration, HS2 is on the same machine that Zeppelin. Is that right?
Also, can you connect from Zeppelin host to the port of HS2?
To test:

```
telnet hive_host hive_port (default 10000)
```

In the hive jdbc strings, it's usual to have a '/' after the port to give the DB to connect in, yours is empty, I recommend altering this string to:

```
jdbc:hive2://$HIVE_HOST:$HIVE_PORT/{DB}
```

If you insert nothing in {DB} HS2 will connect to the database default.